# force close and android.view.InflateException on tablet

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, exception, inflate

For some reason, whenever I try to launch my fragment, I get these errors:

```
12-27 16:54:52.345: D/OpenGLRenderer(4506): Enabling debug mode 0
12-27 16:54:53.775: D/AndroidRuntime(4506): Shutting down VM
12-27 16:54:53.775: W/dalvikvm(4506): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40be4930)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.twfs.thewholefnshow/info.twfs.thewholefnshow.ILikeWrestlingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at info.twfs.thewholefnshow.ILikeWrestlingActivity.onCreate(ILikeWrestlingActivity.java:16)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     ... 11 more
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-27 16:54:53.785: E/AndroidRuntime(4506):     ... 21 more
```

What perplexes me is that this only happens when running the app on my tablet, not my phone. I have tried to replace the XML completely, and get the same error. I have checked the manifest and there are no errors in name or anything else.

Any ideas as to what could cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

In the `ILikeWrestlingActivity` class, you inflate a xml layout. This xml layout will be placed in the folder `res/layout-sw600 or something` of your project.

In this file, line 7, you use a fragment that has no `android:name` attribute.

Comment: I don't have an "android:name" attribute in any of the xml files, why does that matter?

Also, having added the attribute, I still get the errors.

And as mentioned, the app launches fine on my phone, just not my tablet.

Comment: The problem is that your app doesn't use the same layout on your phone and tablet. That's the way it works on android. So in the layout file that is used by the tablet, an attribute is missing for a fragment. Look at an example (here for instance : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). You will see that each fragment *must* have a name attribute, that's the way you indicate which class is used as a fragment. I don't see how a fragment can work without specifying its name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just some strange bug with the XML file. I made a copy of the XML file with a different file name, inflated with that file instead, and it works like a charm now.

I'm not too sure what fixed it, but I've got it working.